# Sorting multidimensional array in a table PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to sort only the "Name" value on a table but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$fruits = array(
      array(
        'image' => '<img class="img" src="papaya.jpg">',
        'name' => 'Papaya',
        'description'=> 'Color: Yellow',
      ),

  array(
    'image' => '<img class="img" src="blueberry.jpg">',
    'name' => 'Blueberry',
    'description'=> 'Color: Blue',
  ),

  array(
    'image' => '<img class="img" src="orange.jpg">',
    'name' => 'Orange',
    'description'=> 'Color: Orange',
  ),
);
array_multisort($fruits['name'], SORT_ASC);
```

I wanted the output to be like this:

| Image | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pic | Blueberry | Color: Blue |
| pic | Orange | Color: Orange |
| pic | Papaya | Color: Yellow |

Comment: Have you tried using `usort` with a custom callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `usort` function with appropriate callback function. You can do it like this.

```
$fruits = array(
    array(
        'image' => '<img class="img" src="papaya.jpg">',
        'name' => 'Papaya',
        'description' => 'Color: Yellow',
    ),

    array(
        'image' => '<img class="img" src="blueberry.jpg">',
        'name' => 'Blueberry',
        'description' => 'Color: Blue',
    ),

    array(
        'image' => '<img class="img" src="orange.jpg">',
        'name' => 'Orange',
        'description' => 'Color: Orange',
    ),
);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}


usort($fruits, "cmp");
```

Comment: saved me a lot of time figuring it out. thank you so much! :)